# IN clause with CASE WHEN in SQL

Tags: sql, db2

I try to count the number of times a product is ordered two days in a row, over the last seven days.
I tried to implement an IN condition in a CASE WHEN, but I get the following error:
`Comparison operator IN not valid`

I'm using DB2

Here is what I've tried :

```
        WITH CTE AS (
            SELECT ALLPIC, COUNT(DISTINCT(PAL.CODPRO)) AS NBREFSSTOCKS
            FROM FGE50NEUV1.GEPAL AS PAL INNER JOIN FGE50NEUV1.GEPIC AS PIC ON PAL.CODPRO = PIC.CODPRO
            GROUP BY ALLPIC
        ),
        CTE2 AS (
            SELECT ALLSTS AS ALLPIC, COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATPRB1 = ` + dateWMS() + ` THEN CODPRO END) AS NBREFSCDE,
            COUNT(
                DISTINCT CASE WHEN (
                    CODPRO IN (SELECT DISTINCT(CODPRO) FROM FGE50NEUV1.GESUPD WHERE DATPRB1 = 20221027) 
                    AND CODPRO IN (SELECT DISTINCT(CODPRO) FROM FGE50NEUV1.GESUPD WHERE DATPRB1 = 20221028) 
                    THEN CODPRO END
                )
            ) AS NBCOMMUNVEILLE,
            COUNT(
                DISTINCT CASE WHEN (
                    CODPRO IN (SELECT DISTINCT(CODPRO) FROM FGE50NEUV1.GESUPD WHERE DATPRB1 = 20221026) 
                    AND CODPRO IN (SELECT DISTINCT(CODPRO) FROM FGE50NEUV1.GESUPD WHERE DATPRB1 = 20221027) 
                    THEN CODPRO END
                )
            ) AS NBCOMMUNJM2
            
            FROM FGE50NEUV1.GESUPD AS SUP
            GROUP BY ALLSTS
        )

        SELECT * FROM CTE INNER JOIN CTE2 ON CTE.ALLPIC = CTE2.ALLPIC ORDER BY CTE.ALLPIC
```

Comment: What's your Db2 platform and version? What's the exact error code and message?

Comment: {
      state: '42000',
      code: -115,
      message: '[IBM][Pilote ODBC System i Access][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0115 - Opérateur de comparaison IN incorrect.'
    }

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a _set quantifer_. `SELECT DISTINCT` will give you distinct _rows_. Simply write `SELECT DISTINCT CODPRO FROM ...` to make code clearer.

Answer (score 0):

[Listing of SQL messages](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.5?topic=codes-listing-sql-messages):

> **SQL0115**
> *Message Text:*
> Comparison operator &1 not valid.
>
> *Cause Text:*
> Simple comparison operators other than equal and not equal cannot be
> used with a list of items. ANY, ALL, and SOME comparison operators
> must be followed by a fullselect, rather than an expression or a list
> of items. **Subqueries cannot be specified in a JOIN condition or in a
> CASE expression.**
>
> *Recovery Text:*
> Change either the comparison or the
> operand. Try the request again.

Comment: Ok but have you an idea of how can I achieve this

Comment: You should update your question with fully reproducible example of your sample data and the result desired. You may start with a single table like (DATPRB1, CODORD, CODPROD, ...), describe what "product is ordered two days in a row" means in terms of table data. Your sample data should contain examples of various cases: when "product is ordered two days in a row" event is occurred and not occurred. Are you able to provide such an information?

Comment: Doesn't matter about the data, the problem here is how to use IN in case statement, I didn't found any solution for DB2

Comment: It does matter. One may provide you a solution using different technique(s).